# docker-compose fails building image only inside Jenkins container

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose

I have a custom Jenkins container where I have installed docker-compose. 
I also have an application which I am trying to deploy in a pipeline. The initial build of the application with docker works fine and so does running unit tests. However to run integration test I need to bring up both the app and mysql (also running in a container). This is where *docker-compose* enters the picture. It starts up fine, starts mysql but when trying to build the app image it fails with error:

```
path /code/package.json
errno -2
syscall open
enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/code/package.json'
```

However the docker-compose works fine in my machine (not to mention how the docker file builds fine in both my machine and the Jenkins Pipeline running in the Jenkins container)

Here is the docker file:

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /code
COPY package.json /code
RUN npm install mysql2
RUN npm install express
COPY . /code
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

The relevant portion of the docker-compose file:

```
  myapp:
    build: ./app
    depends_on:
      - mysqlc
    container_name: myappc
    volumes:
      - ./app:/code
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

And in the Jenkinsfile, the relevant code:

```
...
    stage('Build image') {
      dir('app') {

        app = docker.build("myimage")
      }
    }
   stage('test'){
      sh 'docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit'
      ...
    }
...
```

Any insights would be deeply appreciated

**Update**: Changed the jenkinsfile to have just this for testing:

```
node {
    def app

    stage('Clone repository') {
        checkout scm
    }
    stage('Build image') {
      dir('app') {
        /* Build the docker image */

        app = docker.build("myimage")
      }
    }
    stage('test'){
      sh 'docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit'
      sh 'docker-comopse down -v'
    }
}
```

And it still fails

This is how I run the Jenkins container:

```
docker run -u root --rm -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 --name jenkcont -v jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock jenk
```

And this is how I created the custom image with docker compose

```
FROM jenkinsci/blueocean

USER root

RUN curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.24.1/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

RUN apk add ca-certificates wget && \
    wget -q -O /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub && \
    GLIBC_VERSION='2.27-r0' && \
    wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk && apk add glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk && \
    wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk && apk add glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}.apk
```

Comment: please, share all the docker commands that run...

Comment: @rok, I added additional information at the bottom of the question. I simplified the Jenkins file for testing to just checkout, build and then docker-compose but it still fails.. Thanks